# Show that each conjugacy class has a particular value for probability after k steps

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I have a permutation group $S_n$ and am performing random transpositions on them. Now there will be a bunch of conjugacy classes as a result of that. P_k_s is the probability that after k transpositions one reaches to a particular permutations of n numbers. It is known that for each element in a conjugacy class this value is the same. 
How can this be proved?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. If $\sigma$ is a random transposition then $\pi\sigma\pi^{-1}$ is a random transposition for every $\pi$.
2. $\pi (\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \dots \sigma_k) \pi^{-1} = (\pi \sigma_1 \pi^{-1}) (\pi \sigma_2 \pi^{-1}) \dots (\pi \sigma_k \pi^{-1})$.